# bash convert hex string to integer code using printf failing

Tags: bash

I am iterating over hex digits in a string using a for loop.  I can extract each hex digit ok, but my code to convert to a number is giving strange values.  How can I fix this code?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mystring="5e51584a4c"

for (( i = 0; i < ${#mystring}; i = i + 2)); do
    snumber="${mystring:i:2}"
    printf "number as string=%s\n" $snumber
    number=$(printf "%x"  "'${mystring:i:2}")
    printf "number=%d\n" $number
done
```

I am getting this output:

```
number as string=5e
number=35
number as string=51
number=35
number as string=58
number=35
number as string=4a
number=34
number as string=4c
number=34
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `printf` in this case, you can use bash's `$((base#number))` construct.

```
#!/bin/bash -

mystring="5e51584a4c"

for ((i=0; i<${#mystring}; i+=2)); do
    snumber="${mystring:i:2}"
    echo "number as string=${snumber}"
    echo "number=$((16#${snumber}))"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Hex numbers need to have `0x` prefix:

```
printf "%d\n" 0x5e
```

Outputs:

```
94
```

---

```
mystring="5e51584a4c"

for (( i = 0; i < ${#mystring}; i = i + 2)); do
    snumber="${mystring:i:2}"
    printf "number=%d\n" 0x$snumber
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `printf` command is printing the *character code* of the first digit in each substring, because you have the `'` prefix to the argument.  You want a `0x` prefix instead.

When printing as hexadecimal, you can use `%#x` conversion to make `printf` emit the leading `0x` prefix needed by the next usage:

```
number=$(printf '%#x'  "0x${mystring:i:2}")
#                ^^^    ^^
```